# Smartpy restrict entrypoint for originated addresses (KT1)

Tags: smartpy, address, kt1, types, string

I would like to know if the entrypoint of my smart contract is called from an implicit(tz1) or an originated address(KT1). How can i do the check in smartpy?

Looking at the Smartpy documentation, it's said that the address type sp.TAddress is "An address of a contract or implicit account". Further you can't convert the address to string because Michelson doesn't allow type casting.

Am i missing something? How can i differentiate between the address types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically interested in the address of your caller there a simpler solution than the one proposed by @rodrigo-quelhas: `sp.sender` is an implicit account if and only if it is exactly `sp.source`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils

**Usage:**

```
Utils = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils/main/smartpy/utils.py");

# And then inside the entrypoint

Utils.Address.is_kt1(sp.address("tz28QJHLyqvaY2rXAoFZTbxrXeD88NA8wscC")) # False
Utils.Address.is_kt1(sp.address("KT18hYjnko76SBVv6TaCT4kU6B32mJk6JWLZ")) # True
```

You can check the code here: https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils/blob/main/smartpy/utils.py#L301

Documented here: https://github.com/RomarQ/tezos-sc-utils/blob/main/smartpy/README.md#documentation

**Explanation:**

- Addresses of implicit accounts are strictly less than addresses of originated accounts;
- Addresses of the same type are compared lexicographically;
- `KT1XvNYseNDJJ6Kw27qhSEDF8ys8JhDopzfG` is the highest `KT1` address;
- `KT18amZmM5W7qDWVt2pH6uj7sCEd3kbzLrHT` is the lowest `KT1` address;
- Any `address` in between (including) those two addresses is an originated account;

Comment: how and why are those the highest and lowest KT1 addresses?

Comment: The addresses that you see are a slice of bytes encoded to base58check. The lowest is [2, 90, 121, 0, 0, 0, ....] and the highest is [2, 90, 121, 255, 255, 255, ....], where the first 3 bytes represent the prefix (KT1).

Comment: what would the tz version of this look like (in terms of the first n bytes)?